# Not able to find Cypress.exe file in latest Direct download package for windows from cypress.io

Tags: cypress

Not able to find Cypress.exe file in latest Direct download older from cypress.io

Steps to Reproduce:
1) visit Cypress.io website and click on direct download link (IM using Windows OS)
2) Cypress.zip will get downloaded
3) unzip as regular process into destination folder 
4) open Cypress Folder and we can see cypress.exe file which will open Cypress tool.

Actual Result: Latest version downloaded but when unzipped package, not able to find cypress.exe file. Its getting extracted as cypress.app folder and not as executable file.

Expected Result: There should be some file to launch cypress tool

Comment: This has now been fixed - sorry about the inconvenience, Cypress downloads should now work normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that earlier today as well.

Maybe the direct download OS version checker isn't working correctly? Dunno.

You can however download a specific version via a direct url

So ie. for version 3.2.0 for windows you would use

> https://download.cypress.io/desktop/3.2.0?platform=win

[Installing Cypress](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/getting-started/installing-cypress.html#Hosting)

Comment: Hey, to help us fix this, can you share what browser/OS are you using? Can you share your user agent from this site? http://whatsmyuseragent.org/

Comment: Sure. :-)
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.86 Safari/537.36

Comment: Thanks a ton. This has now been fixed!